# How do I gain magic as a Ranger?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, character-advancement

I heard there was a way to give your ranger Magic, not by weapons and armor. Is that true? If so how do I gain it? What level and what types of magic can a ranger get? The book I've been reading for this information is  the *Players Handbook*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation trying to discern the sources of the asker's confusion has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124172/discussion-on-question-by-devils-spawn-how-do-i-gain-magic-as-a-ranger).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Reach 2nd level.

The Ranger gains the [Spellcasting feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Spellcasting-297) at 2nd level (*Player's Handbook*, pg. 91):

> By the time you reach 2nd level, you have learned to use the magical essence of nature to cast spells, much as a druid does.

The ranger is what is commonly called a "half-caster", the highest level spells they can ever cast is 5th, which they can do starting at 17th level. The ranger learns spells from the [Ranger spell list](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=5&filter-search=&filter-sub-class=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-unlocked-content=) (PHB, pg. 209).